Generate a XLS file using SQL CLR That does not have loads of incompatible Dependencies
I want to do something simple, Create a SQL CLR that converts data to XLS.
I've tried Using OpenXML, but it keeps installing windowbase as a dependency, which uses system.XAML, which SQL server (2019) refuses to install as it's not "tested" whatever that means.
ClosedXML has a similar issue, System.Drawing refuses to be referenced.
I tried writing raw xml to xls and The io.Compression dependency file won't work with SQL server either!
I'm out of ideas, All I really want is a version of openXML that isn't using WPF Nonsense like system.xaml, but I can't seem to get that to work.
Any help is appreciated.

Retrieve the rows in a c# client, in a datagrid for example, and convert the datagrid ? I am sure there are lots of libraries that can help with that

Getting the data isn't the part that is stopping me, but the actual conversion to an XLS. OpenXML and CLosedXML are recommended but both have severe incompatibablities with SQL server assemblies

You can use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). It has Excel Destination Adapter.

This sounds kinda off-topic. Do you need to use CLR? If you're closed off from the outside due to rights, you can use a service or a job that processes some rows and generates xls off-process

Why, out of interest, do you want an XLS, rather than an XLSX file? The former are for much older Excel files.

SSIS requires a source data table that it draws data off, this needs to be entierly dynamic. And it's entierly possible I missed an option that allows that but as far as i'm aware SSIS won't accept a dynamic string parameter

Is the structure of your data the same each time, @Sean ? If so then yes, SSIS would be easily able to do it. If it's not, then no; SSIS expects the definition of your data to be the same each time.

@Tom A I am just trying to get it to work, I assumed XLS is less of a hassle to get to work than XLSX, if there is a method to generate XLSX's that doesn't have these problems I am open to it

@thom A, the structure would be completely dynamic, so the file generated could have completley different column structure from the next

Why are you married to doing this from CLR? SQL Server isn't really designed for exporting data (to a file system); why not using something else to? Does it have to be an XLS(X) file? Could it, for example be a CSV file instead (which can be opened in Excel, though it's also a great fan of destroying them, due to its poor assumptions on data typing).

I'm not married to it being a CLR, in fact if there is an alternative that doesn't use CLR's that would be better. However my research into SSIS and agent jobs simply don't have the ability to create fully dynamic XLSX files. I have already gotten CSV to work but apparently this isn't good enough (Don't ask me why.)

Well a CSV in Powershell would be trivial. Just use DbaTools's Export-DbaDbTableData function.

How to create Excel File Dynamically by using Script Task in SSIS: https://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/03/how-to-create-excel-file-dynamically.html

DocumentFormat.Openxml only supports .xlsx, not .xls. The same goes for ClosedXml which states: ClosedXML is a .NET library for reading, manipulating and writing Excel 2007+ (.xlsx, .xlsm) files. It aims to provide an intuitive and user-friendly interface to dealing with the underlying OpenXML API.

The following may be of interest: SQL Server CLR Supported Libraries

I tried writing raw xml to xls. .xls isn't XML, however .xlsx is.

CLR is pretty much a dead-end, which is a bit sad, kind of like xml support, i guess microsoft were too busy wth AI and other shiny new tools to actually make it secure enough / upgrade the .net libs. If you have full control of your server and ain't afraid of holes, you can still use it by running them as unsafe. There's also sp_execute_external_script or xp_cmdshell, but they have similar security implications

Don't try do this in SQLCLR.  Instead Build a .NET console application to do the work, and invoke it from an Agent job or even xp_cmdshell.
In modern .NET you can even combine your app and all the dependencies into a single .exe as a Single-File Application.

The idea was to circumvent xp cmdshell due to security concerns. But I'm now starting to think that this entire process simply isn't fit for a sql clr and am going to look for alternatives like you suggested.
